# How to write the dynamic method calling code below?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, metaprogramming

> Define a class dynamically. Class name should be taken from user by standard input (command line)
>
> Then prompt user for a method name and a single line of code. This method should be defined as instance method in the class above dynamically with the code entered by user.
>
> Tell user that the class and method is defined. Then call this instance method and display the result.

I am able to create the class dynamically but after that I am not able to proceed.

```
class Ancestor; end
SomeClass = Class.new(Ancestor) do
  def initialize(var)
     print "#{self.class} initialized with #{var}"
  end
end

class << self
 define_method :new_dynamic_method do
    "content goes here"
 end
end

puts a = SomeClass.new(ARGV[0])
```

Code should be object oriented.

Expected Result :

> Please enter the class name: User
>
> Please enter the method name you wish to define: greet
>
> Please enter the method's code: "Welcome from #{self.class} class. I am #{self}"

--- Result ---

> Hello, Your class User with method greet is ready. Calling: User.new.greet: "Welcome from User class. I am "

Calling API should look something like:

```
my_class = DynamicClass.new(class_name)
my_class.def_method(method_name, method_body)
my_class.def_method(another_method_name, method_body)
...
...

my_class.call(method_name)
my_class.call(another_method_name)
```

Comment: This question switches between your voice (what you are saying) and quotes from your homework (essentially your lecturer's voice). I have added some quotes to help decipher this, but it is still confusing. For the "Result" section, is that the "Actual result", to be contrasted against the "Expected Result"?

Comment: You have "Hello, Your class User with method greet is ready" as actual output, but this could not have come from your code, as that does not contain those strings.

Comment: It would be a good idea to clarify the title, so that it is more specific. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just look at the core problem, not obtaining input from the user or displaying information to be read by the user. We obtain the following from the user:

```
class_name  = "User"
method_name = "greet"
code_str    = "Welcome from #{self.class} class. I am #{self}"
  #=> "Welcome from Object class. I am main"
```

Create a class:

```
cl = Class.new
  #=> #<Class:0x0000563cd2e3d748>
```

Name the class:

```
Object.const_set(class_name, cl)
  #=> User
```

Create an instance method for the class:

```
cl.define_method(method_name) { code_str }
  #=> :greet
```

Confirm the class has been created and list the instance methods owned by that class:

```
User.is_a? Class
  #=> true

User.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:greet]
```

Execute the class' instance method<sup>1</sup>:

```
User.new.greet
  #=> "Welcome from Object class. I am main"
```

See [Class::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html#method-c-new) and [Module#const_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-const_set), [Module#define_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method) and [Module#instance_methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods).

<sup>1. The setter of the question may have wanted `User.new.greet` to return `"Welcome from User class. I am #<User:0x00005cb777dca6f0> "`, but that is not possible as `#{self}` was evaluated to its current value when `code_str` was assigned, as shown above.</sup>

Comment: I can see now that I have not gone far enough in answering the question, though I think what I've written so far may be of some help to the OP and possibly other readers. The reference to `DynamicClass` makes the question rather challenging, particularly the need for `self` to be an instance of `User`, and not `User` itself (very odd, that). I may work on it some more, but maybe not.

Comment: Sir I had a small query ... can we take user input in below format.

Comment: class_name  = gets.chomp, 
 method_name = gets.chomp, 
 code_str    = gets.chomp

Comment: Yes, recognizing that if, for `code_str`, the user inputs `"Welcome from #{self.class} class. I am #{self}"`, `code_str` will equal `"Welcome from Object class. I am main"`. I'm curious where this question came from. The reference to `DynamicClass` suggests that it's from a Ruby metaprogramming course, intended for advanced Rubyests.

Comment: Reference: Programming Ruby
By: Dave Thomas, Chad Fowler, and Andy Hunt
From: The Pragmatic Programmers
Edition: Fourth Edition

*Reference: Metaprogramming Ruby 2 *

Comment: Abhinav, I couldn't find the problem in either of the two references. If it's there could you tell me which reference it's in and the page number?

Comment: No Sir.. I meant to say concepts are referred from that book. These questions was just randomly created from one among those concepts.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes sir.. certainly. I have just started reading this book and learning these concepts.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sir your solutions inspire me a lot. Thanks for providing me clarity in this beginner phase.

Comment: I'm glad to help, Abhinav. This is a tough question for a beginner.